# Folder sharing in Virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, shared-folders

I am using Windows 10 pro as host machine and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS as my virtual machine in the Oracle Virtualbox.I created a shared folder in my host and it is permanent.When I start my virtual machine the folder is automatically mounted and I have to select a folder in my virtual machine in order to share files between these two machines. These folders get connected while using the virtual machine. But when I restart my vm , the guest folder seems to be disconnected again. I need to use the sudo command again to connect them. Is there any way-out such that these two folders get connected forever and I don't have to use the sudo command on startup??=
Is there any feature in Virtualbox such that I can do drag and drop between the two machines??

Comment: When creating a shared folder I check "Auto-mount" and "Make Permanent" and end up with a permanent desktop icon for the folder. For drag and drop select "Settings" / "General" / "Advanced" and "Bidirectional" for "Shared Clipboard" and "Drag'n'Drop"

Comment: what about the folder created on virtual machine??

Comment: I want to connect the virtual folder with the host folder forever!!

Comment: Have you tried checking "Auto-mount" and "Make Permanent", I think "Make Permanent" is the most important. Forever is a long time though.